# Sharpziplib get partial/incomplete decompression

Tags: c#, gzip, unzip

I have an incomplete stream of compressed data that was compressed using GZip. I was wondering if it is possible to use Sharpziplib to not throw an error and output what have been decompressed?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var data = new byte[]
        {
            0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xEB, 0x0C, 0xF0, 0x73, 0xE7, 0xE5, 0x92,
            0xE2, 0x62, 0x60, 0x60, 0xE0, 0xF5, 0xF4, 0x70, 0x09, 0x62, 0x60, 0x60, 0xFC, 0x02, 0xC2, 0x1C, 0x4C,
            0x40, 0x11, 0x97, 0x2D, 0x1E, 0x77, 0x81, 0x14, 0x67, 0x81, 0x47, 0x64, 0x31, 0x03, 0x03, 0xDF, 0x11,
            0x10, 0x66, 0x9C, 0xAA, 0xCD, 0x27, 0xCD, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xDE, 0xE8, 0xE9, 0xE2
        };

        using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            inputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            inputStream.Position = 0;

            using (Stream decompressStream = new GZipInputStream(inputStream))
            {
                using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[50000];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int size = decompressStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (size > 0)
                        {
                            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    decompressStream.Close();
                    outputStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your read buffer size `1` instead of `50000`, and perhaps squeeze out the available bytes.

In any case, what you can get from that truncated gzip stream is:

```
89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52
00 00 01 f4 00 00 01 f4 08 02 00 00 00 44 b4 48
dd 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0e c4 00 00 0e
c4 01 95 2b 0e 1b 00 00 07 81 49 44
```

What you have there is the start of a PNG file for a 500x500 RGB image, but no image data. There is an IHDR chunk, a pHYs chunk, and the barest start of what appears to be an IDAT chunk (which would have actual image data), but only through the "ID" part of the chunk name.